# Scripts launched from the Mininet Python API stop working after awhile

Tags: python, mininet, pymodbus

I am trying to write some automated tests in **mininet** which purpose is:

- To create a simple topology
- To run some communication between a server and a client
- To collect some data and stop after awhile

I can run these test by running a miniedit configuration and manually starting the server and client scripts on two terminals connected to the hosts, this scenario works fine.

However I'm trying to do so with the Python API but the scripts I launch on the hosts stop working correctly after a few packets are exchanged. As I said before these two scripts work fine if I launch them manually on two terminals so I think there could be another problem.
I originally thought this could be a bug on the modules I am using to implement the server and client scripts (**pyModbus** and **pyModbusTCP**) but the fact that they work with no problems when launched manually leads me to think that I could be doing something wrong in the way I launch the scripts via the Python API.

This is the script which launches the simulation:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                            

from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

# The first argument is the project path
clientPath = sys.argv[1] + 'test/integration/test_training/client.py'
serverPath = sys.argv[1] + 'test/integration/test_training/server.py'

class SingleSwitchTopo(Topo):
  def build(self, n=2):
    switch = self.addSwitch('s1')
    for h in range(n):
      host = self.addHost('h%s' % (h + 1))
      self.addLink(host, switch)

def test():
  topo = SingleSwitchTopo(n=2)
  net = Mininet(topo)
  net.start()
  hosts = net.hosts
  server = hosts[0]
  client = hosts[1]
  # Start the server process in the background
  server.sendCmd('python3 ' + serverPath)
  # Start the client and print the output
  client.cmdPrint('python3 ' + clientPath)
  # Here there would be the rest of the test

if __name__ == '__main__':
  setLogLevel('info')
  test()
```

When this script is launched the logs show that the responses are correctly received by the client for some time. However, at a certain point the server will always start to send empty responses, this never happens when I run the scripts manually on a miniedit configuration.

These are the server and client scripts (these are simple pyModbus and pyModbusTCP scripts which are given as default examples):

#### Server

This server basically updates some values periodically and listens for queries.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext

from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

server_ip = '10.0.0.1'
server_port = 502
start_address = 1
final_address = [1]*100

#LOG
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

init_val = 0

# updating server function
def updating_server(a):
    log.debug("updating PLC registers..")
    context = a[0]
    register = 4
    slave_id = 0x00
    address = 0
    values = context[slave_id].getValues(register, address, count=5)
    values = [v + 1 for v in values]
    log.debug("new values: " + str(values))
    context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, values)

store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [1]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [2]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [3]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [init_val]*100))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName = 'Pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.0'

#server run and update
time = 0.5
loop = LoopingCall(f=updating_server, a=(context,))
loop.start(time, now=False)

StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=(server_ip, server_port))
```

### Client

This client connects to the server and periodically sends queries.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
import time

server_ip = '10.0.0.1'
server_port = 502

c = ModbusClient(host=server_ip, port=server_port, auto_open=True)
c.debug(True)

while True:
  if c.is_open():
    # read 5 input registers starting at address 0
    values = c.read_input_registers(0, 5)
    print(values)
    time.sleep(0.1)
  else:
    c.open()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I've been banging my head for some time on this issue and can't find a solution. Am I missing something?